# Changes in Magento core files

Tags: magento

I'm about to release a Magento based app on production and I am performing some final checks on licensing to make sure everything is correct. From what I understand, Magento core files should not be changed. Otherwise, the changes need to be shared (or something like that). So I'm trying to determine this but I have 2 main issues:

1. I can't really check if the core files were changed. My app uses Magento 1.9.2.1 but our core files are way different then a clean Magento 1.9.2.1 core. Why? Because we have applied SUPEE security patches along the way. So performing a diff won't help me determine if there are any core changes. Is there any other way to determine if the core files were changed in any way by one of the developers?
2. Due to infrastructure issues, we had to adapt Mage.php to change the chmods to a different permission (0777 instead of 0750 and 0640). Is this considered a core change? As I'm not certain if this file is considered part of the core files. Since the Mage class is final, we can't really extend it to make any changes.

Thanks in advance for any info

Comment: For 2 point - Yes it is core change and not recommended. For 1 Point - You can install your extension in fresh magento and check its functionality. If there is core code change then it will not work as expected

Comment: Setting permissions to 777 is just bad, bad, bad. You might as well publish your credit card details online (don't forget the expiry date CCV).